# LsaLogonUser user with multiple ids mapped to one smart card certificate

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-authentication, msdn, credential-providers

I'm working on an app in which I've to validate  a user  using smart card  certificate. Where one certificate is mapped to multiple ids.

Windows (credential provider) logs in user  in such environment by using "Hint" attribute along with "Pin" .

I want to achieve the same with LsalogonUser api. The problem is there is no "hint" field in structure  "KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON".

```
typedef struct _KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON {
  KERB_LOGON_SUBMIT_TYPE MessageType;
  UNICODE_STRING         DomainName;
  UNICODE_STRING         UserName;
  UNICODE_STRING         Pin;
  ULONG                  Flags;
  ULONG                  CspDataLength;
  PUCHAR                 CspData;
} KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON, *PKERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON;
```

I have working code for the scenario where one certificate is mapped to one id.

source: https://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/LsaSmartCardLogon.cpp

My question is how does Microsoft windows credential provider validate the user with "hint" attribute ?

What can I do to pass "Hint" attribute to LsaLogonUser api so that it can correctly validate the user?

Thanks,